After changing the idents of cells in seurat, how can I get back to original ident?
I am analysing the scRNA-seq data using Seurat, in the annotation step, I change the idents of cell manually using the function RenameIdents:
new.cluster.ids <- c("Naive CD4 T", "CD14+ Mono", "Memory CD4 T", "B", "CD8 T", "FCGR3A+ Mono",
    "NK", "DC", "Platelet")
names(new.cluster.ids) <- levels(pbmc)
pbmc <- RenameIdents(pbmc, new.cluster.ids)

Now I want to get back to the original indent which uses number such as 0 1 2 3...

It's possible that the original identities are encoded in the Seurat object under the name orig.ident.
old.cluster.ids <- pbmc$orig.ident

I prefer explicitly creating a new named metadata value in the Seurat object for each new feature I want to add, including the initial clusters:
pbmc$seurat.clusterID <- Idents(pbmc)
pbmc$cluster.names <- new.cluster.ids

More details about identity modifications can be found here:
https://satijalab.org/seurat/articles/essential_commands.html
Most Seurat functions allow you to specify the identity using the ident parameter, which means you can often create workflows that don't need to ever explicitly change the default identity.
